# Subset rows from list of dataframe

Tags: r, list, lapply

I want to subset rows,say from 130:150, in each dataframe present in a list. I have written a below code to subset:

```
test<-lapply(res,subset, [130:150,]) # res contains the list of dataframes
```

But this code is throwing below error:

```
Error in res[130:150, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your tittle says "select column" and you ask to subset rows

Comment: Could you put your data in the question, by using dput(res)?

Answer (score 3):

```
res <- list(mtcars,mtcars)
lapply(res, function(x) return(x[2:4,]))
```

is returning the *rows* 2 to 4 of each dataframe. If you want the *columns*, use

```
lapply(res, function(x) return(x[,2:4]))
```

or Gregors solution `lapply(res, "[", 2:4)`

Comment: Also possible without the anonymous function: `lapply(res, "[", 2:4)`

Comment: @shosaco, still I am getting the same error: incorrect number of dimensions. My list contains 100 dataframes. How to pass that in the list function?

Comment: @Gregor, Thanks it's working.

Comment: Your solution is returning the columns, not the rows! I suspect that is what User0590 wanted, but asked for rows instead.